# Create sum type in C implementation of OCaml function

Tags: c, ocaml, ml

Let's say you had a type declaration:

```
type foo = Bar | Baz of int
```

How would you implement a [C function](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual033.html) to create a Baz?  Let's say I declare it like this:

```
external create_baz : int -> foo = "create_baz"
```

Then I would need to fill out this code:

```
CAMLprim value create_baz(value bar) {
  // what do I do here?
}
```

I understand that this is a rather silly thing to do, but it's just and example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in [Chapter 19 of the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html).

Basically, constructors are numbered in order, in two separate sequences. Nullary constructors (those taking no values, like `Bar`) are numbered in one sequence, and constructors that take a value (like `Baz`) are numbered in a second sequence. So both of your constructors are numbered 0.

Nullary constructors are represented by immediate values (a simple bit pattern representing a value like an int). Constructors taking values are represented by pointers to blocks, which have fields that can store the contained values.

So, basically your function wants to make a block of size 1 with tag 0. `bar` is saved in the block's 0th field (the only field).

It looks something like this:

```
value create_baz(value bar) {
    // Caller guarantees that bar is an int.
    //
    CAMLparam1(bar);
    CAMLlocal1(result);
    result = caml_alloc(1, 0);
    Store_field(result, 0, bar);
    CAMLreturn(result);
}
```

Comment: What part of that tells it that it's a "Baz"?

Comment: Another read about variants in C, http://www.linux-nantes.org/~fmonnier/ocaml/ocaml-wrapping-c.html#ref_enums

Comment: The fact that the result is a block says that it's one of the constructors that takes a value. The fact that the tag is 0 says it's the *first* constructor that takes a value. Hence, `Baz`. See Section 19.3.4.